# Test data missing values

Tags: python, dataset, pandas

I've been given a test and train data set, and I have null values in my test data set. What do I do with it?

Comment: Why are they null? This is an important question to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Impute them using only the train data. Do not impute them using the test set as it will lead to data leakage.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's important to differentiate **between null values in your features or null values in your target value**.

Null values for features, there exist several ways to impute null values **check this sklearn doc https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html**

As @spectre pointed out is mandatory **avoid data lakeage** e.g compute the mean of your dataset, and then use that mean to impute null values in your test dataset. To avoid that, I highly recommend the use of imputers combined with sklearn pipelines, below a couple of links with examples.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html

https://towardsdatascience.com/improve-your-data-preprocessing-with-columntransformer-and-pipelines-b6ff7edd2f77